# Entity Framework: select records that don't exist in relationship

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling to get a list of students that are missing required courses.

I have a many to many relation using a joining table:

Student:

```cs
public class Student: IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    private string _name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value!.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    // removed additional fields for brevity
}
```

Course:

```cs
public class Course: IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    private string _name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value!.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public bool Required { get; set; }

    // removed additional fields for brevity
}
```

Action:

```cs
public class Action: IBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
    
    // the date that the student took the course
    public Datetime AttendedDate { get; set; }

    // removed additional fields for brevity
}
```

How to get a list of students that are missing required courses?

For instance as a `Dictionary<string, Student>`, where string is the course and the student that **didn't** take the course.

I tried a `foreach(var s in Students)` and inside a `foreach(var c in courses)`, but it hangs...

```cs
Dictionary<string, Student> dict = new();

foreach (var s in Students)
{
    foreach (var c in Courses)
    {
        bool exists = actions.Any(x => x.Student.ID.Equals(c.ID) && x.Course.ID.Equals(c.ID));

        if (!exists)
        {
            dict.Add(r.Name, c);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm doing the relationship in a wrong way?

Any help is appreciated.

PS: sorry about my English, not my first language.

Comment: If Action is your junction table (StudentCourses) then your keys are wrong. Remove the GUID PK and add the PK and a FK constraint to Student and Course.

Comment: Have you added all navigation properties? Also do you need that on the server side or as answered below with whole tables in memory?

Comment: @GHDevOps Action is my junction table as you stated Entity Framework maps the constraints and create the keys:
`public Student Student { get; set; }
 public Course Course { get; set; }`

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't need the data on the server side, only on client to show the user the studants that are missing the required courses.

For instance Jane has yet to complete 2 required courses, that are course A and D...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must test `x.Student.ID.Equals(s.ID)` not `c.ID`.

And you cannot add duplicate keys to a dictionary. E.g., add the `s` and missing `c` to a `List<(Student student, Course course)>` instead, where the list contains tuples.

```cs
List<(Student student, Course course)> missing = new();
foreach (var s in Students) {
    foreach (var c in Courses) {
        bool exists = actions.Any(a => a.Student.ID == s.ID && a.Course.ID == c.ID);
        if (!exists) {
            missing.Add((s, c));
        }
    }
}

foreach (var (student, course) in missing) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{student.Name} did not attend \"{course.Name}\"");
}
```

Comment: sorry `x.Student.ID.Equals(c.ID)` was a typo, ill try your sample and  report back, thank you!

Comment: Perfect working as expected, Thank You! @Olivier Jacot-Descombes